# Failed to install screen module, which exists in directory

Tags: react-native, expo

When I try to run app on emulator or device by snack.expo, I get this error:

> Device: (741:6637) Failed to install module 'project_modules/containers/<%name%>': Failed to download module 'project_modules~containers~<%name%>@latest'
>    imported from app.js

<%name%> can be changed between different screens, all from directory project_modules/containers/
Code:

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import AuthScreen from 'project_modules/containers/auth_screen'
import SelectProjectScreen from     'project_modules/containers/select_project_screen'
import ProjectScreen from 'project_modules/containers/project_screen'
import SelectTaskScreen from 'project_modules/containers/project_select_task_screen'
import TeamScreen from 'project_modules/containers/project_team_screen'
import CamerasScreen from 'project_modules/containers/project_cameras_screen'
import store from "./project_modules/instances/store";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {INITIAL_PARAMS} from "./project_modules/constants/state_constants/project_constants";

const Root = createStackNavigator({
    SelectProject: {screen: SelectProjectScreen},
    ProjectScreen: {screen: ProjectScreen},
    SelectTaskScreen: {screen: SelectTaskScreen},
    TeamScreen: {screen: TeamScreen},
    CamerasScreen: {screen: CamerasScreen},
    AuthScreen: {screen: AuthScreen}
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthScreen',
    initialRouteParams: INITIAL_PARAMS
});

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Root/>
        </Provider>
    )
};

export default App
```

> index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SIBM', () => App);
```

> package.json

```
{
    "name": "SIBM",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "core-decorators": "^0.20.0",
        "expo": "^27.0.1",
        "firebase": "^5.0.3",
        "react": "16.3.1",
        "react-native": "0.55.4",
        "react-native-dropdownalert": "^3.4.0",
        "react-native-fontawesome": "^5.7.0",
        "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
        "react-navigation": "^2.0.1",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "redux": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-env": "^2.4.1",
        "jest": "22.4.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
        "eslint": "^4.19.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
        "webpack": "^4.8.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react|react-native|react-navigation)"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/"
        ]    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem solves with absolute path packaging.
I added to every big directory their own *package.json* with field "name". Then i get imports like this:

```
import AuthScreen from 'containers/auth_screen'
```